# Why this succesfull Swift async call with POST params is not returning what espected

Tags: ios, json, swift, asynchronous, swift2

I have researched a lot to do an async call with post params in swift and finally I've managed to do a succesfull one but now, when I parse the json it throws an error because my json parse function is not able to parse the response data and returns nil instead of a json object.

I've set breakpoints and the check the variables, the values are alright and the async call seems to succeed, but the return data have php errors, and I'm pretty sure the error "fault" is not from the server because I've simulated the same call, with same params and url form [hulr.it](http://www.hurl.it)
and the return data is the json token and nothing else.

this is the returned data:

[image]

this is the detailed returned data with the token as a proof the user has been registered and the call is ok:
[image]

And this is the code of my async call:

```
      private func callWithCompletionHandler(completed : completionAsyncCall){
        asyncJson.removeAllObjects()

        //Set async call params
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: self.url!)!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let trimmedPostParam : String = self.paramString!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())

        request.HTTPBody = trimmedPostParam.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil && data != nil else {
                // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }
            if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

//            asyncJson = responseString!.parseJSONString! as! NSMutableArray

            let result : AnyObject = responseString!.parseJSONString!

                if let nsMutableResult = result as? NSMutableArray{
                    print("NSMutableArray")
                }
                if let nsDictResult = result as? NSMutableDictionary{
                    self.parseMutableDictionary(nsDictResult)
                }


            self.flag = true  // true if download succeed,false otherwise
            completed(success: flagAsyncCall!)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

I absolutely need json data in return. Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It appears that your php had an error on line 41. Were you supposed to provide a last_name value?

Comment: if php code has an error in line 41, why it doesn't show the error when I do the same call from hurl.it?

Comment: Because you provided different input?  The error message is quite clear though

Comment: diferent input? One call is made from the app, the other call is being simulated in hurl.it. What do you mean by diferent input? The url and post params are exactly the same...

Comment: Obviously they aren't since the server gets an error with whatever your swift code is posting.

Comment: programming ain't no magic man, the things you send from hurl are not the same as it oviously isnt working.

Comment: that's the thing. Why the call isn't the same if the code is alright and the params are equal? Or is the code wrong? In that case can you show me what part?

Answer (score 1):

I seriously suggest not rolling your own networking code, it's ugly and prone to stupid errors. Use Alamofire instead. The error returned IS a server error (service shouldnt return freakin' html in case of error btw, it should return a json with reason of failure or something like this) Anyway, it's probably happening because you're sending a wrong request. Also, if you're using a JSON as your POST body, you should send something like:

```
let parameter: NSDictionary = ["firstParam": firstValue, "secondParam": secondValue]
let dataContainer = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameter, options: NSJSONWritingOptions() )

request.HTTPBody = dataContainer
```

Not a trimmed string.

Comment: well it's an internal server error, does the service use JSON for body protocol? Also, check your headers. Are you using Application/JSON as your content type?

Comment: Note that the server may return any content type - even when an Accept header has been explicitly specified in the request, for example `application/json`. So, sending HTML when an error occurred is not a wrong behaviour of the server.  In your sample, you did not specify a content header (which you should), thus the server will either assume the content is of type `application/octet-stream` or it may try to figure it out. In case of JSON, that can fail miserably. So, set the content header to `application/json`. See also your first sentence ;)

Comment: That's right, it worked the way you said. Post it as answer if you want the points. Thanks!